# Problems after upgrade do 23.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, updates, 23.04

I yesterday upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04 on my laptop. All went fine, but after rebooting, I have the following problems:

- No more Dash after login. If I go to Settings, to ubuntu desktop pane, I get the message

  > No Ubuntu settings found.

  In the *About* pane, I get the message *Not available* for *GNOME version*.
- If I do:

  ```
  sudo apt install -f
  ```

  I get:

  ```
  3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
  ```
- If I do:

  ```
  sudo apt list --upgradable -a
  ```

  I get:

  ```
  Listing... Done
  python3-distupgrade/lunar-updates,lunar-updates 1:23.04.6 all [upgradable from : 1:23.04.5]
  python3-distupgrade/lunar,lunar,now 1:23.04.5 all [installed, upgradable to : 1:23.04.6]

  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/lunar-updates,lunar-updates 1:23.04.6 all [upgradable from : 1:23.04.5]
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/lunar,lunar,now 1:23.04.5 alL [installed, upgradable to : 1:23.04.6]

  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk/lunar-updates,lunar-updates 1:23.04.6 all [upgradable from : 1:23.04.5]
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk/lunar,lunar,now 1:23.04.5 all [installed, upgradable to : 1:23.04.6]
  ```
- And last problem, Firefox has lost my profile, and asks to create a new one (which I did and is fine).

Comment: You are asking many different questions here. Please [edit] your question to only one of them (possibly to the one about upgrading packages, as [you already have an answer for that](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464514/618353)) and ask each of the rest as separate questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove any existing local extensions.

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/
rm -rf extensions
```

Then log in again and it now should load the desktop successfully. I'm not sure why this situation occurred in the first place, but this fixed it on my machine.

Note that you will need to re-install any custom extensions again, from http://extensions.gnome.org.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem, that's perfect. Many thanks. Moreover, I had the same problem with my other computer, so your help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that after upgrading to 23.04 I also noticed the Gnome Version is Not Available in the About section of settings and also "No ubuntu settings found" in the Ubuntu Desktop section of the settings.

I do not have the other problems with broken installation mentioned by Philippe.

I tried reinstalling gnome and gnome-shell but that did not solve the problem.
if I type:
gnome-shell --version
I get:
GNOME Shell 44.0

I shall update this thread with my finding as I investigate this issue.

Update 1: I changed the Nvidia driver from nvidia-driver-525-server to nvidia-driver-525 and rebooted, after that I now can see the gnome version number 44.0 in the about section, however the "ubuntu Desktop" section still showing a sad face with "No ubuntu settings found" error.

Update 2: When you first login to gnome, you may choose from a menu at the bottom right corner either "Gnome" or "ubuntu" as a desktop. I found out that the "ubuntu Desktop" does not show up in the Setting menu if I choose "Gnome". Which matches the description shown in the Gnome Release Notes shown in this link:
https://release.gnome.org/44/

Answer (score 1):

I removed all existing extensions I could and installed the Dash to Dock extension and now things seem to be working just fine.