# Autostart of Gnome Shell Extensions on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I just upgraded from 22.04 to 23.04. Under 22.04 if I logout or reboot and then login the extensions I had been running restarts. On 23.04 when I login they are all off, and I have to go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to toggle them on.

I don't recall something special on 22.04 to make the setting stick. By the way, I was, and am running Xorg not Wayland.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gnome Shell failed to load extensions after Ubuntu 23.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465183/gnome-shell-failed-to-load-extensions-after-ubuntu-23-04-upgrade)