# Gnome Extensions fail to load (Dash to Panel, ArcMenu, Bing Image, etc) after suspend/resume after Ubuntu 23.04 upgrade

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 just last week and it was a smooth one. However, it seems my Gnome-Extensions does not load correctly after I resume from a suspended session. I have updated Extensions to be Gnome 44 compatible, and installed recommended packages and also rebooted a couple of times but it has not made any difference. If I were to disable and re-enable Gnome Extensions, they start working again. And this is my current work-around. I would love to get Dash to Panel and Arc menu extensions working again, and appreciate any help. - Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have the same issue. I hope an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove all extensions and reinstall it.

The solution is from Ross Dobson :

[Gnome Shell failed to load extensions after Ubuntu 23.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465183/gnome-shell-failed-to-load-extensions-after-ubuntu-23-04-upgrade)

Comment: Only removing "ding@rastersoft.com" from extensions folder solved the problem (from https://askubuntu.com/a/1478073/1181107)

Install it from source using the ubuntu_install.sh script